# Set Memory Device Status to Online

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine

I added memory to my Linux VM while machine was up. I cannot reboot the vm so I must set the device status to online manually. I use following command to do this:

```
[root@myVM ~]# echo "online" | tee /sys/devices/system/memory/memory4*/state
```

But I got this error:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It would depend on your distribution and kernel settings. For examples see [VMware KB Hot adding memory in Linux (1012764)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012764). This does assume your distribution/kernel supports hotplugging memory in the first place. if it doesn't, you will need to reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been sold. Linux was needed available memory to increase memory. Example, If we want to increase to 16G from 4G we should increase to +100M firstly. Then we can set status of devices to online.